# how private key is stored?

Tags: private-key, copay

How is the private key or master seed managed on iOS or Android?
In copay, using Secure Enclave? And as for Android device how is the private key or master seed managed?

Comment: There are too many third party wallets for this to be answerable, and if you want to know about a specific wallet (that is not Bitcoin Core), you will need to ask them about their implementation